# ParseRelation<ParseUser> Object not found

Tags: xamarin.ios, parse-platform

I created a ParseRelation and it shows up in the Data Browser but when i click to view the relations it says object not found. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code because I am able to add other relations properly.

```
ParseRelation<PersonalCaseFile> cases = p.GetRelation<PersonalCaseFile>("PersonalCaseFiles");
PersonalCaseFile case_file = new PersonalCaseFile ();
case_file.CaseID = "239827";

ParseRelation<ParseUser> suspects = case_file.GetRelation<ParseUser> ("CurrentSuspects");

await case_file.SaveAsync ();
cases.Add (case_file);

suspects.Add(ParseUser.CurrentUser);

await p.SaveAsync ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should have tried this first but I can actually query the data just fine in code. Maybe it's just an issue with the data browser.